# Setting static IP on second adapter in /etc/network/interfaces breaks first dhcp connection

Tags: networking, dhcp

I have two adapters, the first will always have a static IP and the second will always get IP via DHCP.  Currently, my second adapter gets it's IP via DHCP but cannot be pinged/accessed in any way over the network.  If I remove the static IP assignment from Port #1, then I now have a fully functioning network on the DHCP adapter.

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# Port 1
auto enp1s0
    iface enp1s0 inet static
    address 10.0.0.107
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 10.0.0.1

# Port 2
allow-hotplug enp2s0
iface enp2s0 inet dhcp
```

So what should I changed so that my port #1 static IP assignment doesn't interfere with the Port #2 DHCP network?